# Setting Barlow as CSS font in my stylesheet

Tags: html, css, font-family

I wan to set Barlow and Fraunces in my CSS. But every time i try to import and use that font family, there doesn't seem to be any changes and font still seems to be Times New Roman.

I tried this

```
@import url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Barlow);
body{
    font-family: 'Barlow';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to include your `font-weight` and `font-style` properties in your CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body{
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<style>
body { 
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```